# Javascript not working - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this javascript code, which is supposed to work according to a tutorial in internet. But, this isn't working. I don't know what is the problem in the code. Please check:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#nav2 li a').hover(function()
    {
        var offset=$(this).offset();
        var thiswidth =$(this).width()+13;
        $('#nav2 li.ybg').stop().aimate({left:offset.left+9+"px",width:thiswidth+"px"},400,function(){
            $(this).aimate({height:"28px"},150);
        });    
    },
    function()
    {
        $('#nav2 li.ybg').stop().aimate({height:"4px"},150,function(){
            $(this).aimate({left:"165px",width:"55px"},600,'easeOutBounce');
        });    
    }); 

});
</script>
```

All the class, ID name and the tag name are correct. But, this isn't working :( here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HVueJ/ 
The yellow bar is supposed to move.

Comment: There is typo errors on animate in your jsfiddle

Comment: Here is proper jsfiddle version of your incorrect code: http://jsfiddle.net/HVueJ/3/. If you have a look at the console you will see the output: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'aimate'`. That should explain everything...

Answer (score 3):

You have mistake there in the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#nav2 li a').hover(function()
    {
        var offset=$(this).offset();
        var thiswidth =$(this).width()+13;
        $('#nav2 li.ybg').stop().animate({left:offset.left+9+"px",width:thiswidth+"px"},400,function(){
            $(this).animate({height:"28px"},150);
        });    
    },
    function()
    {
        $('#nav2 li.ybg').stop().animate({height:"4px"},150,function(){
            $(this).animate({left:"165px",width:"55px"},600,'easeOutBounce');
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

Should be this. You spelled `animate` as `aimate`

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HVueJ/1/

Answer (score 1):

There is typo errors in your code. You wrote "animate" as aimate

Comment: TypeError: $("#nav2 li.ybg").stop().aimate is not a function